# Increment and Decrement by 1 value when click on + and - button

Tags: jquery

I have a sum calculation process in jQuery that looks like this:

```
<th>Name</th>
<th>Vote</th>
<th>Action</th>

<tr>
   <td>User A</td>
   <td class="vote">5</td>
   <td>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary addVote">+</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary subVote">-</a>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>User B</td>
   <td class="vote">3</td>
   <td>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary addVote">+</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary subVote">-</a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
$(function() {
   $(".addVote").each(function() {
     var vote    = $('td.vote').text(),
         newVote = parseInt(suara) + parseInt(1);

     $(this).on('click', function() {
        $('td.vote').text(newVote);
     });
   });
});
```

What I want to achieve is when I click '+' button, the **newVote** value should replace the **vote** value and the process will continue every time '+' button is clicked. The same process should happen if '-' button is clicked. I can do this just one time. Next process nothing happens. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it would work for you

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('table').on('click','.addVote, .subVote', function() {
        var _vote= $(this).closest('tr').find('td.vote');
         var change = $(this).hasClass('addVote') ? 1 : -1;
         _vote.text((parseInt(_vote.text())+change));
     });
   });
```

Check this fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/36udn5Lv/2/

Comment: I think , this is optimized solution with lightweight load of execution then Roma's Answer. so If you like this answer please check it right.

Answer (score 2):

Please try following snippet.

```js
$(function() {
   $(".addVote").click(function() {
     $(this).parents('tr').find('td.vote').html(parseInt($(this).parents('tr').find('td.vote').html())+1);
   });
   $(".subVote").click(function() {
     $(this).parents('tr').find('td.vote').html(parseInt($(this).parents('tr').find('td.vote').html())-1);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<table>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Vote</th>
<th>Action</th>

<tr>
   <td>User A</td>
   <td class="vote">5</td>
   <td>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary addVote">+</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary subVote">-</a>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>User B</td>
   <td class="vote">3</td>
   <td>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary addVote">+</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary subVote">-</a>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```
            <html>
            <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Vote</th>
                    <th>Action</th>

                    <tr>
                        <td>User A</td>
                        <td class="vote">5</td>
                        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary addVote">+</a> <a
                            href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary subVote">-</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>User B</td>
                        <td class="vote">3</td>
                        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary addVote">+</a> <a
                            href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary subVote">-</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <script>
                                $(function() {
                                     $(".addVote").click(function() {
                                          var vote = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.vote').text();
                                         var newvote = parseInt(vote)+parseInt(1);
                                         $(this).closest('tr').find('td.vote').text(newvote);   
                                     });    
                                     $(".subVote").click(function() {
                                          var vote = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.vote').text();
                                         var newvote = parseInt(vote)-parseInt(1);
                                         $(this).closest('tr').find('td.vote').text(newvote);   
                                     });    
                                });
               </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Its working. Thankyou! All answers are working fine.